# Any way to reorder the RegExs in Productivity Power Tools' Custom Document Well?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, productivity-power-tools

When using the Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools' Custom Document Well feature, the user has the ability to specify regular expressions by which to color the tabs.  This works as expected, however I often want to re-order the regular expressions (since they're applied in top-down order), and there doesn't seem to be any way to do so (there also doesn't seem to be a way to delete existing Reg. Ex. rows).  You can select a row and a little arrow appears on the left, but I don't seem to be able to use that to move the row up or down, and dragging the row doesn't do anything either.  Am I missing something?  I can get what I want by manually rewriting each of the Reg. Ex.s to be in the order I desire, but that's a time consuming process for something so simple.  Thanks!